# Instead of throwing an error type block executed successfully

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Recently i have read about UDT. i have created a type but i have a problem with that one. please look into the following

```
---drop type ssn
CREATE TYPE ssn
FROM VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL;

DECLARE @er ssn;

IF Object_id('TEMPDB.DBO.#ter', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #ter;

CREATE TABLE #ter (
    PERIOD_SID INT
    ,PERIOD_QUAR VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY (PERIOD_SID)
    )

INSERT INTO #ter (
    PERIOD_SID
    ,PERIOD_QUAR
    )
SELECT *
FROM (
    VALUES (
        (1)
        ,(@er)
        )
    ) V(p, q)
```

I have create a type ssn with varchar(11) not null, and ran the above one logic, it execute successfully
[image]

As per my assumption it should throw an error.

I need to know why the above logic run successfully.

**EDIT**

as per suggestion i have added this udt as a column in AQL server , since in oracle we can create a column with collections similar to UDT

```
IF Object_id('TEMPDB.DBO.#ter1', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #ter1;

CREATE TABLE #ter1 (
    PERIOD_SID INT
    ,PERIOD_QUAR ssn PRIMARY KEY (PERIOD_SID)
    )
```

[image]

An error was encounter while creating the table saying there was no such datatype "ssn"

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which error did you expect to get?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I would like to expect like null value cannot be assign to er variable

Comment: In SQL Server we can `declare` a `variable` with *initializing* it(defaults to `NULL`). So it voids the `NOT NULL` property of `UDT`. Not sure why it allowed to mention NOT NULL property in UDT.

Comment: `DECLARE @er ssn;` is same as `DECLARE @er ssn = NULL`. Question can be simplified by removing the `Create` and `Insert` statements. Just `Select @er` after declaring. It will be `NULL`

Comment: Thanks for the Quick reply Prdp, But our UDT allowed to create a datatype with not null so as per my understanding that variable shouldn't allow nulls when we inherit this datatype

Comment: @Smart003 - some reason might me there. Wait someone will come up with an explanation

Comment: Which line, specifically, would you expect an error to occur on?

Comment: I think when use the data type `ssn` while creating tables it will not allow the column to store `NOT NULL` values

Comment: Prdp please have a look on the updated one

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  I would like to expect like null value cannot be assign to er variable

Comment: But until SQL Server 2008 (IIRC), you could not declare and assign a variable in a single statement. So the variable declaration line itself cannot throw an error. And then the poor innocent `INSERT` statement isn't, itself, trying to assign a value to something of type `ssn` - merely reading one. `@er` isn't referenced anywhere else, so there's no natural location to *raise* an error.

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever I have used SQL server 2012 for the above one

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [reason](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addtype-transact-sql)

> The null_type parameter only defines the default nullability for this
>   data type. If nullability is explicitly defined when the alias data
>   type is used during table creation, it takes precedence over the
>   defined nullability.

This is taken from `sp_addtype` but it should be the same case with `CREATE TYPE`. `sp_addtype` is also used to create user defined data type

In your case, we cannot create a variable which will not accept `NOT NULL` values. So I think the property is overridden